# Get Windows Server status using WMI in C#

Tags: c#, windows, wmi

i need service thats starts automatically on the Windows Server. 
Can someone show me a way to get the Status of the Windows Server (Online or Offline) using WMI.

Thank you in advance

Comment: check the complete example here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt703458(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try below code,

```
string FullComputerName = "<Name of Remote Computer>";
            ConnectionOptions options = new ConnectionOptions();
            ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope("\\\\" + FullComputerName + "\\root\\cimv2", options);
            scope.Connect();
            ObjectQuery query = new ObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_TerminalService");
            ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query);
            ManagementObjectCollection queryCollection = searcher.Get();
            foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in queryCollection)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------");
                Console.WriteLine("Win32_TerminalService instance");
                Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------");
                Console.WriteLine("Started: {0}", queryObj["Started"]);
                Console.WriteLine("State: {0}", queryObj["State"]);
                Console.WriteLine("Status: {0}", queryObj["Status"]);
            }
```

Source :- https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/a25d3071-2283-41c6-9262-6860d7965963/how-to-check-remote-servers-terminal-status-using-c?forum=csharpgeneral

Comment: I never did something like this before. I want connect to my Hyper-V Cluster on my Windows Server. Where i need to write what to do this?

Comment: How about the query to get all services?